# Same react codebase on Mac and Linux, works on Mac but won't run on Linux due to errors?

Tags: javascript, linux, reactjs, macos

Devs, why would 'react-scripts build' command show "import" and "default export" errors on the Linux but not on the Mac? Same codebase. Is there a config or environmental var that allows you to ignore errors in jsx files during this process?

My issue is that I have the same codebase that I am trying to get setup on both a Mac and a Linux, both computer have the same package versions installed, use the same command to run (i.e. `npm start`). My issue is that while the program can get up and running on the Mac just fine, on Linux it stops right after `installing dependencies...` line, indicating that there is some error that is preventing the program from running fully, both programs are being run from Visual Studio Code.

A suspicion of a friend is that there is some configuration setup possible on the Mac that is forcing the build script to ignore certain errors during the build process, thereby allowing the program to run despite having errors. This appears to have been confirmed when I once found a random error in the react code - fixed it - attempted to run the script again and it stopped due to a different error. While I don't have time to run through the entire codebase looking for small errors like this, **I would be interested know if there is such a script that is forcing the react build to ignore said errors and if so where can I locate it on Windows/Linux and fix it?**

Thanks again!

Comment: Title and first paragraph describe the situation differently. The title says that it does work on Mac but not on Linux; the first paragraph says it works on Mac and Linux but does not work on Linux. Which is it? Also what exactly are the errors?

Comment: @Pointy Sorry for the confusion, but it does NOT work on the Linux, while it does work on the Mac. The error is essentially saying that a component is not being exported by default correctly but it while it exists in both codebases the linux will not allow the program to run while the mac will